# how to redirect example.com with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

how to redirect example.com to example.com/market using .htaccess file

ex.

```
http://example.com/details.php?id=3667 and
http://www.example.com/details.php?id=3667
```

should redirected to

```
http://example.com/market/details.php?id=3667
```

and also I want to redirect any example.com to example.com/market

using htaccess

Answer (score 1):

According to [here](http://dense13.com/blog/2008/02/27/redirecting-non-www-to-www-with-htaccess/) for:

**Redirecting www to non-www**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Redirect root to subfolder**

```
Redirect / http://example.com/market
```

Comment: i mean redirect the main directory to market folder, and this is not working

Comment: i want to redirect http://www.dkakeen.com/details.php?id=anynumber to http://www.dkakeen.com/market/details.php?id=anynumber

Comment: now only example.com is redirected, how to make it also www.example.com?

Comment: You shouldn't specify any new redirect only for www, but instead, redirect www version to non-www either by htaccess or using records on your DNS (of course if you're on a dedicated server, not a shared hosting)